# Postgres: How to casting JSONB value to numeric

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am having issues casting a jsonb value.  And would love some guidance.

what we are trying to achieve is that some data came in as strings, and we want to cast that to numbers.

Consider the following update statement:

```
update customer
set traits = jsonb_set(traits, '{arr}',traits->'arr'::text::integer)
where jsonb_typeof(traits->'arr') = 'string'
  and traits->'arr' is not null
```

We currently get the following error:

`[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "arr"`

I have tried all sort of casting incantations, but can't figure away past this.

Anyone have a path forward for us ?!

---

working solution looks like THIS:

```
update customer
set traits = jsonb_set(traits, '{arr}',(traits->>'arr')::integer::text::jsonb)
where jsonb_typeof(traits->'arr') = 'string'
  and traits->'arr' is not null
```

with a triple cast.  Smells a bit off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your expression

```
traits->'arr'::text::integer
```

is evaluated as

```
traits->('arr'::text::integer)
```

which is trying to cast `'arr'` to an integer (failing for obvious reasons with the error message you mention). Instead, you want

```
(traits->'arr')::text::integer
-- or
(traits->>'arr')::integer
```

Comment: I think thats the ticket -- but still have a follow up issue with my jsonb_set.  `[42883] ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 30`

is my path syntax incorrect??

Comment: @Jonathan I think because `jsonb_set` is overloaded, postgres isn't clever enough to infer the type of the `'{arr}'` literal. You need to write `'{arr}'::text[]` (`ARRAY['arr']` might also work).

Comment: this is what I had to do -- does this make sense to you / feel right??:
`update customer
set traits = jsonb_set(traits, '{arr}',(traits->>'arr')::integer::text::jsonb)
where jsonb_typeof(traits->'arr') = 'string'
  and traits->'arr' is not null`

Comment: It doesn't f"eel right" to me as I would hope there would be a simpler/shorter/better way, but it's probably the correct way to do it.

Comment: Instead of `int_value::text::jsonb` one can do `to_jsonb(int_value)`, that makes it look better.

Answer (score 1):

Since Postgres 14, you can do:

```
UPDATE customer
SET traits['arr'] = traits['arr']::integer::text::jsonb
WHERE jsonb_typeof(traits['arr']) = 'string'
  AND traits['arr'] IS NOT null;
```